# Is there an issue in fast refreshing materialized view every 1 min?

Tags: database, oracle, refresh, materialized-views

I need to refresh my materialized views every 1 minute so I used the following code:

```
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW Any_Name
BUILD IMMEDIATE 
REFRESH fast start with (sysdate) next  (sysdate+1/1440) with rowid
ON DEMAND 
AS
SELECT * FROM AnyTable@DB_Link;
```

I will apply this code to 7 tables that rarely updated but when the tables updated it's important that materialized views refresh quickly.

Is there a problem in fast refreshing materialized view every 1 min?

Comment: Are they not suitable for fast refresh on commit?

Comment: No,they are suitable.
But i am asking even if it fast i am afraid that 1 min interval costs performance issues at the database?

Comment: If you [refresh on commit](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/statements_6002.htm#SQLRF54159) then you don't need to refresh every minute though. You won't have that overhead and you won't have gap between a table being updated and the MV reflecting the changed data, which seems to be what you are trying to avoid in the first place.

Comment: @AlexPoole
I can't to use refresh on commit because it works only if the master table in the same database which it is not my case (Check this [link](http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_ora_12054_cannot_set_on_commit_refresh_materialized_view.htm) )

Comment: I won't add this as an answer, since it's unlikely that you are on version 12.2 of the database yet.  But look into the `enable on query computation` option of materialized views in 12.2 for an idea of how this question might be answered in the future.

Answer (score 0):

1. I believe that is another question related to optimization without any information. Performance depends on how many RPM you have to your DB (to this view)? how longs it refresh/how big tables are ? 
   It is linked tables so they probably on other server. Maybe you need to refresh just slice of data (Change the architecture of your DB and refresh small materialized view) just in case ?
2. Also I'm not sure, but in case of **refresh mat view** you could have much more REDO logs instead of simple **truncate insert /*+ append */** and this could be a big problem of performance (to often bottleneck of the problem in hard drives)

Comment: I think what you asking will not differ in fast refresh?

Comment: It's differ. Fast refresh you can call "incremental refresh" (© Kyte) so it is generate redo and undo logs instead of way I suggested. But as I already wrote it's not enough information.